# Using findAll to extract text from Span Tag using Beautifulsoup returns an empty list

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A beginner at web-scraping here. I'd like to extract "47" from the span class of the following HTML code:

```
<a href="https://www.walkscore.com/score/loc/lat=39.87797546386719/lng=-104.80396270751953/?utm_source=zillow2.com&amp;utm_medium=ws_api&amp;utm_campaign=ws_api" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="ws-value" aria-describedby="walk-score-text">
   <span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 hdp__sc-1af0wis-4 ifWvNt">
       47
   </span>
</a>
```

I have tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/9991-Joplin-St-Commerce-City-CO-80022/58649635_zpid/'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html")

info = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 hdp__sc-1af0wis-4 ifWvNt'})

print(info)
```

But this returns an empty list. Can someone please help explain why?

Comment: `Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 hdp__sc-1af0wis-4 ifWvN` is actually multiple classes (spaces divides classes). Try to search by any 1 class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see ("Walk Score") is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. To get the value you can simulate Ajax request:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.zillow.com/graphql/"

property_id = 58649635

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}
params = {"zpid": property_id, "operationName": "WalkAndTransitScoreQuery"}
query = {
    "clientVersion": "home-details/6.0.11.5878.master.4328f5c",
    "operationName": "WalkAndTransitScoreQuery",
    "query": "query WalkAndTransitScoreQuery($zpid: ID!) {\n  property(zpid: $zpid) {\n    id\n    walkScore {\n      walkscore\n      description\n      ws_link\n    }\n    transitScore {\n      transit_score\n      description\n      ws_link\n    }\n  }\n}\n",
    "variables": {"zpid": property_id},
}


data = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, params=params, json=query).json()

print("Walk Score:", data["data"]["property"]["walkScore"]["walkscore"])
```

Prints:

```
Walk Score: 47
```